# Magento- Unknown Administrator User

Tags: php, security, magento, authentication, administrator

I think I am in a bit of trouble...
I was developing online store for past month, when I have finished I changed the hosting to new company. Transferred files and database...

Today I go to System->Permissions->Users and besides me I see one unknown account.
I check this account and it's also an administrator! So I think someone hacked into my website. 
During development I didn't remove install folder from my server so maybe he got there by this... Is there any other way someone could do it?
And most importantly do you reckon my password that I use to login to magento back end was compromised?

I will greatly appreciate all of the answers and tips how to make my website secure. Thank you.

Comment: Did you personally do the migration, or did someone else do it for you? (IE: the hosting company).

Comment: This happens on Magento versions that need the SUPEE 5344 patch installed, it's called the ShopLift bug. You can insert a fully functional administrator by just sending a POST link to the site without even having to log in.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Your comment seems very useful and might be better suited as an answer. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you find an unknown user account in users list, click to open the account. Then, click the Delete User button.
After that you need to install all new security patches like
SUPEE-1533
SUPEE-5344
SUPEE-5994
SUPEE-6285
For installing security patches you need to download thease security patches from magento store 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download
and after that you need to upload thease patches from magento root directory and run command via terminal like 
sh SUPEE-1533(name of this downloaded patch)
repeat this for all patches
and after sucessfull installing this pathes enter you site url here
https://shoplift.byte.nl/
and then what happens
and also you can see a list of file name in you file app/etc/applied.patches.list

Hope it will help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento recently make some security upgrade issue.

Use [this](https://templates-master.com/supeechecker) link to check if the patch is applied on you store.
If not, I recommend to you make the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you find an unknown user account in users list, click to open the account. Then, click the **Delete User** button.

**Important:** Install latest security patches.

To learn how to install a patch check this link out:
https://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

To check your store security use the following link:

http://magento.com/security-patch